# VBA PowerPoint unable to save presentation

Tags: vba, excel, templates, powerpoint

I'm trying to pull together a marco that add data and charts from Excel into a powerpoint template and save it in a directory. The macro is being run from Excel.

After running it, the following message appears:

```
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':

Presentation (unknown member): PowerPoint was unable to open or save this document. Please ensure that you have access priviliges to read or write the document that is not encrypted.
```

Below is the VBA code:

```
Sub CreateMPP()

Dim DestinationTemplate As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myTemplate As PowerPoint.Presentation

DestinationTemplate = "C:\Users\Me\Documents\MPP_Template.potx"
Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PowerPointApp.Visible = True

Set myTemplate = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationTemplate, ReadOnly:=msoFalse)

'Other macro that pulls the data and charts, which works perfectly fine
Call CreatePowerPointTest

myTemplate.SaveAs "TestTest", ppSaveAsPresentation
myTemplate.Close

PowerPointApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Try msoTrue for ReadOnly?

Comment: Where exactly are you saving the presentation? Since you haven’t provided a path (SaveAs), it is possible that the save is happening in a folder where you may not have write access.

Comment: @Jbjstam I've tried that, but unfortunately that didn't make a difference

Comment: Thanks @ShyamPillai! Specifying the path along with the filename did work!